# Fingerprint image to ANSI/ISO template

Tags: android, fingerprint, iso, biometrics

My requirement is to:

1. Develop an android app which capture fingerprint images.
2. Grayscale captured images
3. Extract minutiae from each grayscale image and get ANSI and ISO template.

**Problem**

I am trying to achieve 3rd point i.e extract minutiae.

**Research**

I tried following tools:

[SourceAFIS](https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/) - 
A good library on fingerprint but its JAVA port don't extract template.

[NIST's BiomDI](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/biomdi-software-tools-supporting-standard-biometric-data-interchange) - 
It contains many C-based tools for fingerprint. Contacted their technical support, which said you need separate software to extract features, BiomDI is for manipulation extracted features.

[Innovatrics](https://github.com/lunter/ansi_iso_sdk_java_connector) and [SecuGen](https://secugen.com/products/sdk/) code for Android - Innovatircs need to set license in code but it have a method for image to template conversion. SecuGen needs to initailized from USB manager

Please advise which way to follow to achieve this conversion.

Comment: How do you capture fingerprint image ? with an external fingerprint reader ? if yes which one ?

Comment: @LaurentY, image is captured through mobile camera.

Comment: Did you check theses libraries support extraction from camera ? I think only fingerprint reader is supported

Comment: @LaurentY, yes, SourceAFIS and Innovatrics libraries support extraction from images. Actually they accept byte[] of PNG or Bitmap. These all support fingerprint reader also.

Comment: Ok they accept image but from which source ? camera or only fingerprint reader ? I doubt camera (from market smartphone) could provide a image for fingerprint matching

Comment: @LaurentY, they accept the image from camera. In SourceAFIS example project, we can see it reading image from project directory. Similarly, we can provide it image from camera.

Comment: A simple search on googlegive me this:
https://sourceforge.net/p/sourceafis/discussion/1051112/thread/3836919c12/?limit=25#533f
https://sourceforge.net/p/sourceafis/discussion/1051112/thread/d0016307/#6c68
https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/custom#benchmarks